# Inflationary Klein Gordon Field, derivation of a result

Tags: cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, klein-gordon-equation

Good afternoon,

I have a problem whilst studying an Inflationary Klein Gordon field theory. The main problem arises when I try to derive the following result: what I have is:

$$\ddot\phi + 3H\dot\phi \dfrac{1 - L\dot\phi^2}{1 - 3L\dot\phi^2} - \frac{V' + \frac{3}{4}L'\dot\phi^4}{1 - 3L\dot\phi^2} = 0$$

What I also have are those:

$$\dot\phi^2 = \frac{1}{L} + \epsilon D$$
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}\left(\frac{1}{L} + 4V\right) = \epsilon f(\phi)$$
$$H^2 = \frac{1}{3M}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2 + \frac{3}{4}L\dot\phi^4 + V\right)$$

**What I should get is**

$$2M D' + \text{sgn}\left(\frac{H}{f}\right)\sqrt{3} D= \frac{M f}{2}$$

Where $V' and L'$ mean derivative upon $\phi$

$\epsilon$ is the first order expansion term (superior orders can be neglected)^2

Any help? Think you so much!